# In app engine where should I put code to access third party api's?

Tags: google-app-engine, design-patterns

I am working on an App Engine application for a school. The application needs to use some of Googles API's to create Groups, Calendars, Drive Folders etc. 
The application has models for things like Classes, Lessons, AssessmentItems. These models will need to have Calendars, Drive Folders and Groups created for them.

Where do I put the code to access the Google API's and create these third party resources?

My first instinct was to put the code in the model but the more I thought about it the more it seemed wrong, now I don't know where to put it.

Comment: why not put it somewhere, try it, see if you have a problem then if you do you can ask a question about it?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Paul C. You can also check if you are calling the APIs via API Console (https://code.google.com/apis/console).